# Using deviation and mean function in Panda Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, error-handling

Ive currently got a set of data as you can see here;

[image]

I am trying to use the .std() and .mean() functions within Panda to find the deviation and mean to reject outliers. Unfortunately I keep getting the error shown below the piece of code. I have no idea why, might be because of the headers not being numerical? I am not sure.

```
def reject_outliers(new1, m=3):
        return new1[abs(new1 - np.mean(new1)) < m * np.std(new1)]
new2 = reject_outliers(new1, m=3)
new2.to_csv('final.csv')
```

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the numeric columns and only apply the transformation to them

```
# get list of numeric columns
numcols = list(new1.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.values

# run function only on numeric columns
new1[numcols] = reject_outliers(new1[numcols], m=3)
```